# Why set parent attributes to the as_view ,effective subclass view?

Tags: python, django

I have a custom class-based view:

```
class GreetingView(View):
    greeting = "Good Day"
    def get(self,request):
       return HttpResponse(self.greeting)

class MorningGreetingView(GreetingView):
    greeting = "Morning to ya"
```

My urls.py set as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'greeting/',GreetingView.as_view(greeting="G'day")),
    #override that in a subclass
    url(r'subgreeting/',MorningGreetingView.as_view()),
    #TODO (is a bug ? why I set the argument for the parent.as_view
    #method ,is effetive to subclass ...
```

]
When i go to the 127.0.0.1:8000/subgreeting/ and it's show me "G'day" That's should be "Morning to ya"! Can someone help me ? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with the regular expressions you are using for your urls. They should be

```
url(r'^greeting/$', GreetingView.as_view(greeting="G'day")),
url(r'^subgreeting/$', MorningGreetingView.as_view()),
```

Notice the `^` and `$`, they mark the startswith and endswith for a regexp.

Without these two, the string 'subgreeting' always matches the regexp 'greeting' as 'greeting' is a substring in 'subgreeting'. This is why the first url is invoked.